# How to override settings.py with settings_local.py in Django 1.11

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm quite new in Django 1.11.1

I want to ask how to override `settings.py` with `settings_local.py`

in my **settings.py** I have:

```
...
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
...
try:
   from settings_local import *
except ImportError:
   pass
```

in my **settings_local.py** I have:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
        'USER': 'USER_NAME',
        'PASSWORD': 'PASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

but everytime I do `python manage.py migrate`, the table only created in `sqlite3` not in `postgresql`.

I already try to find and use the solution that already provided by other user and already install `psycopg2`, but still, cannot do it. Is there something wrong with my settings?

Regards,

Comment: put import at the top of DATABASES declaration

Comment: Not related to your problem, but this seems the wrong way round; normally you would run sqlite in development and postgres in production.

Comment: @mohammad still only migrated to sqlite

Comment: @DanielRoseman I prefer to run with postgresql in local and prod

Comment: Well, me too. In which case why have this override at all? Why not set it to postgres in the main settings file?

Comment: You solution should work. Can you please post full settings.py

Comment: By silenting any error that could occur when importing `settings_local` you shoot yourself in the foot. Replace the "pass" statement in your except clause by a "raise", and you will probably have a clue on why it's not working.... This being said using the same backend everywhere would be better.

Comment: @L_S I only use the default settings with additional with settings_local.py

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers thank you for the correction

Comment: @JohnElmerSemaya Did you tried my answer ?

Comment: @L_S I didn't try your answer. Might be possible answer, but I only need `.settings_local`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since I use python 3 maybe the code become a little bit strict, I only have to add `.` just before `settings_local`

```
try:
    from .settings_local import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this? Just declare DATABASES like below in your settings

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
         'NAME': database_name,
         'USER': database_user,
         'PASSWORD': database_password,
         'HOST': 'localhost',
         'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

And in you local settings just declare `database_name`, `database_user`, `database_password`

## EDIT

If you want to have sqlite as default you can define a default_settings.py  and put sqlite declaration in it. at your settings.py import like this.

```
try:
    from local_settings.py import *
except ImportError:
    from default_settings.py import *
```

By this if you want to use postgres just declare it in local_settings but if your partner wants to use sqlite default_settings is imported which defines sqlite as default database.

Comment: I prefer to use sqllite in settings.py because if my partner use it for the first time, they won't accidently use prod database

Comment: @JohnElmerSemaya I editted answer based on your comment

Answer (score 1):

For this I just use this packages https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ.
And another think, I suggest that you use the same engine on production and deployment, because if you are using postgres on development when you deploy to production with Sqlite you can have errors because the postgres has more features in django and errors like that are extremely hard to debug in deployment

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create another 'settings_local.py' file to change your just database setting.

You can directly add your setting in `settings.py` file to set database as PostgreSQL. Please check below code:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'myshopdb',                      # Your database name which you have dreated using command line in PostgreSQL
        'USER': 'admin',                      # Your username which you have created in PostgreSQL for your db.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Your password.
        'HOST': 'localhost',                      # Set to empty string for localhost.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default(8000).
    }
}
```

It should work.

Do not forget to run your project using `virtualenv`. It will help you to secure your project during package installation.

Thanks.

Comment: I prefer to use sqllite in settings.py because if my partner use it for the first time, they won't accidently use prod database

Comment: Okay, in that case, you can just run the command in your shell to apply setting like "django-admin runserver --settings=mysite.settings"   where you can change "mysite.settings" to "mysite. settings_local". please check this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

Answer (score 0):

For me you solution should work. Possible case is `ImportError`.There are multiple cases which should cause this

1. If file is not there (Thats why you put `try except`)
2. Some error in settings_local(random import in settings_local) like

   ```
   import notinstalledmodule
   ```

So the second case also cause `ImportError` that you are catching.So in order to debug this remove the `try except` and make it work (since you have file in local).